# How to bind munin to use a vhost or port number?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, port, munin, virtualhost

Currently I'am able to access my munin setup using the default url. www.mydomain.com/munin

For security reasons, I want to only allow Munin to be access using port number.
Like this

`http://www.mydomain.com:8080/munin`

Tried reading munin config but no luck. Hope that you can suggest on how to configure this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munin is just a "webapp". You need to configure your webserver (Apache, nginx,...) to run on that port.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are talking about the Munin master which usually outputs HTML and images to a given directory which is then subsequently served through a web server.

Without knowing your specific set-up I recommend changing the web server to only bind to a particular IP and port. For example, with Apache, you would use the *Listen* directive and provide and IP + port. E.g. "Listen 127.0.0.1:8080".

Comment: Hi right now I'am able to access munin using http://www.mydomain.com/munin, I have multiple site hosted on a single server and I want to access munin using different vhost and port, www.domain2.com:8080/munin